# How to fix the error "unsafe implementation of PreferenceActivity classes"?

Tags: android

I get the error "Your app(s) are using an unsafe implementation of PreferenceActivity classes that make them susceptible to Fragment Injection." from Google Play.

I have read https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188427?hl=en and [Your implementation of PreferenceActivity is vulnerable to fragment injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278592/your-implementation-of-preferenceactivity-is-vulnerable-to-fragment-injection)

Does it mean that the class PreferenceActivity is obsolete ? How can I fix the problem?

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.unlock"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.08" >

    <uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="9"  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />     

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/unlockwithwifi"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >   


       <activity
            android:name="ui.UnlockMain"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    


        <activity android:name="ui.UnlockAddWiFi"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ui.UnlockAddWiFi" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>             


        <activity android:name="ui.LockPreference">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ui.LockPreference" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>      

        ... 

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LockPreference.java**

```
public class LockPreference  extends PreferenceActivity{

     private AdView adView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.unlockpreference);
            setContentView(R.layout.unlock_custom_preference);

            adView=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            PublicParFun.SetAD(adView);         

            SetDisplayIcon();

            Button btnClose=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClosePreference);
            btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }           
            });         
     } 
     ...    

}
```

**unlockpreference.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="AppPreference"
    android:summary="@string/PreferenceSummary"
    android:title="@string/Preference" >

    <ui.custom.DialogChangePassword
       android:key="ChangePassword"
       android:dialogIcon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
       android:title="@string/ChangePasswordTitle"
       android:summary="@string/ChangePasswordSummary"      
       android:positiveButtonText="@string/BtnSave"
       android:negativeButtonText="@string/BtnCancel"
       android:layout="@layout/unlock_custom_preference_item"  
    />      

    <CheckBoxPreference
       android:defaultValue="true"
       android:key="DisplayNotificationIcon"
       android:title="@string/DisplayNotificationIconTitle"
       android:summary="@string/DisplayNotificationIconSummary"  
       android:layout="@layout/unlock_custom_preference_item" 
    />    

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer way for adding preferences is to use preference fragments in a normal activity. Create a normal activity with frame layout and create preference fragment which will uses preference screen to show preference. 
See this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment see this wiki page it has implementation

Comment: Thanks! Is the class PreferenceActivity obsolete ?

Comment: no its not still obsolete, but  looking from your warning message, its likely that Google will be dropping support for this.

Comment: And more, if the min API is 9, how can I fix the bugs. BTW API 9 don't support PreferenceFragment